# The relation on Descartes product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G/H$ be the group quotient. Consider 
$f: G/H \times G/H \to G/H$ given by $f(\overline{a}, \overline{b}) = \overline{ab}.$ 
Then $f$ is a map.

Here, I have a question.

Why if $(\overline{a}, \overline{b})  = (\overline{c}, \overline{d})\in  G/H \times G/H  $ then $\overline{a} = \overline{c}$ and $\overline{b} = \overline{d}?$

Comment: This is the *definition* of equality on a Cartesian product $A \times B$.

Comment: @Jordan Mitchell Barrett Can you indicate the link of this definition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair